# XSLT: poor performance due to complex XPath expression?

Tags: performance, xslt, xpath

At some point in an XSLT program, I have the following:

```
<xsl:for-each select="tags/tag">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//shows/show[film=//films/film[tag=current()/@id]/@id]|//shows/show[group=//groups/group[film=//films/film[tag=current()/@id]/@id]/@id]">
        <xsl:sort select="date" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
        <xsl:sort select="time" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:for-each>
```

It seems that the XPath expression `//shows/show[film=//films/film[tag=current()/@id]/@id]|//shows/show[group=//groups/group[film=//films/film[tag=current()/@id]/@id]/@id]`, which is rather complex, considerably slows down the execution of the program (compared to the execution time before adding the quoted piece of code -- processing the same data, of course).

Do you think this is normal due to the relatively complex nature of the expression, and do you see how I could improve it so it performs better?

NB: in the XPath expression, `film` and `//films/film`, `group` and `//groups/group` refer to distinct elements.

See below a stripped-down sample of the XML input.

```
<program>
  <tags>
    <tag id="1">Tag1</tag>
    <tag id="2">Tag2</tag>
    <tag id="3">Tag3</tag>
  </tags>
  <films>
    <film id="1">
        Film1
      <tag>2</tag><!-- References: /program/tags/tag/@id=2 -->
    </film>
    <film id="2">
        Film2
      <tag>1</tag><!-- References: /program/tags/tag/@id=1 -->
    </film>
    <film id="3">
        Film3
      <tag>3</tag><!-- References: /program/tags/tag/@id=3 -->
    </film>
    <film id="4">
        Film4
      <tag>3</tag><!-- References: /program/tags/tag/@id=3 -->
    </film>
  </film>
  <groups>
    <group id="1">
      <film>3</film><!-- References: /program/films/film/@id=3 -->
      <film>4</film><!-- References: /program/films/film/@id=4 -->
    </group>
  </groups>
  <shows>
    <show id="1"><!-- Show with film (=simple) -->
      <film>1</film><!-- References: /program/films/film/@id=1 -->
      <date>2011-12-12</date>
      <time>12:00</time>
    </show>
    <show id="2"><!-- Show with group (=combined) -->
      <group>1</group><!-- References: /program/groups/group/@id=1 -->
      <date>2011-12-12</date>
      <time>14:00</time>
    </show>
  </shows>
</program>
```

Explanations:

- A tag is a property attached to a film (in fact, it's rather a category).
- A group is an enumeration of films.
- A show references either a film or a group.
- What I want: for each tag, I'm looking for the shows referencing a film having the current tag and the shows referencing a group where at least one of the films has the current tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer by nonnb very likely points to the problem, however not really to an efficient solution ("cheaper" axis are better, but that alone doesn't make the speed such as when indexing data).

Note that the big problem is that the XPath expression predicate does another full traversal of the tree for each evaluation. You should use keys for stuff like this; this will (in most or even all XSLT implementations) make an indexed lookup possible, thereby reducing the runtime a lot.

Define keys for the films, groups and shows by id:

```
<xsl:key name="filmByTag" match="film" use="tag" />
<xsl:key name="groupsByFilm" match="group" use="tag" />
<xsl:key name="showsByFilm" match="show" use="film" />
<xsl:key name="showsByGroup" match="show" use="group" />
```

And then use it like this (not tested, but you should get the idea):

```
<xsl:variable name="films" select="key('filmByTag', @id)/@id" />
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('showsByFilm', $films)/@id|key('showsByGroups', key('groupsByFilm', $films)/@id)/@id">
```

Answer (score 8):

[Double slashes in XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385272/slow-selectsinglenode) are performance and CPU hogs when working with large documents (since every node in the document must be evaluated). If you can replace it with either an absolute or relative path you should have a noticeable improvement. If you can post the input schema and required output, we could be more specific?

e.g. With an absolute path

```
//shows/show[film=//films/film[tag=current()/@id]/@id]
```

becomes

```
/myroot/somepath/shows/show[film=/myroot/somepath/films/film[tag=current()/@id]/@id]
```

or if the shows and films are relative to the current node

```
./relativexpath/shows/show[film=./relativexpath/somepath/films/film[tag=current()/@id]/@id]
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it now (+1 for the suggestion). I don't have a formal schema for the input, but I could post an example.

Answer (score 4):

Your XPath expression seems to be doing a three-way join so unless it's optimized the performance is likely to be O(n^3) in the size of the source document. Optimization involves replacing the serial searches of the document by indexed lookups. There are two ways of achieving this: you can hand-optimize it by replacing the filter expressions with calls on the key() function (as indicated by Dimitre), or you can use an optimizing XSLT processor such as Saxon-EE, which should do the same optimizations automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Define a key with `xsl:key` and then use the `key` function for the cross reference instead of that comparison you currently have. Show us a sample of the XML so that we can understand its structure, then we can help with concrete code.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I've added the sample to the question

Answer (score 1):

Here are two complete solutions that should exhibit better performance:

**Do note**: Better performance will be registered on sufficiently large input samples only. On small input samples it isn't worth it to optimize.

**I. Not using `//`** (but not using keys)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vFilms" select="/*/films/film"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vShows" select="/*/shows/show"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vGroups" select="/*/groups/group"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vTags" select="/*/tags/tag"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:for-each select="$vTags">
    <xsl:apply-templates select=
     "$vShows
              [film
              =
               $vFilms
                  [tag=current()/@id]
                         /@id

              or
                group
                =
                 $vGroups
                          [film
                          =
                           $vFilms
                              [tag=current()/@id]
                                       /@id
                           ]
                            /@id
               ]
      ">
        <xsl:sort select="date" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
        <xsl:sort select="time" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
   </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="show">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**II. Using keys**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kShowByFilmId" match="show"
          use="film"/>

 <xsl:key name="kShowByGroupId" match="show"
          use="group"/>

 <xsl:key name="kGroupByFilmId" match="group"
          use="film"/>

 <xsl:key name="kFilmByTag" match="film"
          use="tag"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vTags" select="/*/tags/tag"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:for-each select="$vTags">

    <xsl:apply-templates select=
     "key('kShowByFilmId',
          key('kFilmByTag', current()/@id)/@id
          )
     |
      key('kShowByGroupId',
          key('kGroupByFilmId',
              key('kFilmByTag', current()/@id)/@id
              )
               /@id
         )
     ">
        <xsl:sort select="date" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
        <xsl:sort select="time" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
   </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="show">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I believe that your code in II,. is not correct, you're matching show group IDs against film IDs (the indirection via the groups is missing).

Comment: @Lucero: Good catch, thanks. I believe that my edit fixed this. :)

Comment: yep I think that should do it (and this part is now pretty much the same as my answer).

Comment: @Lucero: As you witnessed, I didn't intend to copy your answer :) Whenever when two people independently produce more or less the same solution, this is good!

Comment: of course, I meant my comment as confirmation that I also believe this solution to be correct. ;)

Comment: Thanks @Dimitre and Lucero, I'll carefully study your answers. I'm not very familiar with the keys (although I've used them in the past), that's a good opportunity to learn and get to understand the principle.

Comment: @GlauberRocha: You are welcome. Keys are a key concept and often their use is the only way to achieve high efficiency.